# Print results from mysql query in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to show some results in table, but the query data shows up to the table. Here is the code:

```
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','123','news');
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = <<<SQL
            SELECT Id FROM news
SQL;
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    print "<table><tr><td>№</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        print '<tr><td>'+$row[0]+'</td></tr>';
    }
    print "</table>";
```

The result is like this:

```
1234
№
```

It should look like this:

```
№
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: can you provide the html created in the result?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the "+" with "."
The "+" is used to add values, the "." is used to concatenate strings

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','123','news');
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = <<<SQL
            SELECT Id FROM news
SQL;
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    print "<table><tr><td>№</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        print '<tr><td>' . $row[0] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    print "</table>";
```

or use the following

```
print "<tr><td>$row[0]</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use . Instead of + and use echo instead of print

Answer (score -1):

```html
print '<tr><td>'+$row[0]+\n'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, just a couple words of explanation would go a long way.